# Elasticsearch range query slow matching when combined with a specific filter

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, range-query

I'm trying to figure out why our new cluster is slow and found some weird things.

When executing this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "term": { "reference_id": 4489 } },
        { "range": { "created_at": { "gte": "2020-03-15" }} }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And check the profiling, it looks like it's spending a lot of time in "match":

```
IndexOrDocValuesQuery
created_at:[1584230400000 TO 9223372036854775807]
match, 2.3s, 84.2%
```

If running the following query, which filters on another field (same mapping) it doesn't use any `match` at all:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "term": { "root_id": 3413 } },
        { "range": { "created_at": { "gte": "2020-03-15" }} }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now it just spends some time in `advance` (match is 0):

```
IndexOrDocValuesQuery
created_at:[1584230400000 TO 9223372036854775807]
advance, 376.5ms, 82.5%
```

Both `root_id` and `reference_id` are mapped as `long` (will change to `keyword` as I think it will be faster at least).

Now, the two queries are filtering on different fields, but still the same type of fields, why would it do a slooow "match" in the first query? Any ideas? Can I figure that out somehow?
Also, why is it doing a "match" at all? I only do filtering so no scoring should be done, right?

Comment: Please share your mapping, two or three document examples and the elasticsearch version you are using